# Who is at the mall?

Tags: lateral-thinking, password

My younger sister wanted to play a game with me.

> **She:** You have to say a random word, and I'll tell you a number related to it. In the end, I'll ask you a question, whose answer will
>   open a secret vault. You ready?
>
> **Me:** Well yeah of course! Should I start?
>
> **She:** Yup. Say a word.
>
> **Me:** FOX
>
> **She:** 15
>
> **Me:** WITCH
>
> **She:** 15
>
> **Me:** HASH
>
> **She:** 19
>
> **Me:** MAT
>
> **She** 9
>
> **Me:** MINIMIZE
>
> *Waiting a bit*
>
> **She:** 21
>
> **Me:** LOCK
>
> **She:** 20
>
> **Me:** CLOVE
>
> **She:** 23
>
> **Me:** DONE
>
> **She:** 23. Oh I mean are you ready for the question?
>
> **Me:** Yup
>
> **She:** WHO IS AT THE MALL
>
> **Me:** How will I know?
>
> **She:** It was you who took the challenge. Tell the answer, or......

Me thinking........Puzzling.SE!

*P.S. This is in no way related to any of the questions I've posted recently here*

**Edit (after accepting the answer)** The great minds discovered that the secret vault had [spaghetti](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49359110#49359110). Even my sister couldn't figure it out. Of course as usual she [forgot to plug in the microwave](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49359119#49359119). :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First notice that:

> **Me:** MAT
>  **She** 9
>  **Me:** MINIMIZE
>  **She:** 21

This is

> The number of strokes required to draw the words in capital letters (M=4, A=3, T=2, I=1, Z=3, E=4)

Now

> **Me:** FOX 
>  **She:** 15 
>  **Me:** WITCH
>  **She:** 15 
>  **Me:** HASH
>  **She:** 19

is interpreted

> by O=10, C=5, S=10, which results apparently from a choice (a curve is not made of linear strokes, so it has greater value)

Note that this is confirmed by:

> **Me:** LOCK 
>  **She:** 20 **(2+10+5+3)** 
>  **Me:** CLOVE 
>  **She:** 23 **(5+2+10+2+4)**

Finally

> **Me:** DONE 
>  **She:** 23. Means that **D=6**

So the answer is

> **She:** WHO IS AT THE MALL
>  $$(4+3+10)-(1+10)-(3+2)-(2+3+4)-(4+3+2+2)$$
>  So if the answer is a number (as indicated in the comments below) it has to be
>  $$17115911$$